# Node core modules location

Tags: node.js, fs

After installation of nodejs where can I find the core modules themselves? What is the path to them on my Linux machine? For example I want to see where is the fs module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are compiled into the executable, but their source can be [found here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib).

**EDIT**: I'm not intimately familiar with Node's building process, but from what I understand (mostly from [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c3bd59b9323c9837889414b49a78f8afcc1a02fc/node.gyp#L588-L624)) is that all files in the abovementioned directory are "converted" to C++ using [`tools/js2c.py`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/c3bd59b9323c9837889414b49a78f8afcc1a02fc/tools/js2c.py) and the results are written to an intermediate file `node_javascript.cc` during the building process.

I assume that they hook somewhere into the module/bindings system of Node so that when you use, for instance, `require('fs')`, Node will look in its internal list of modules first.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to explain what you mean by 'compiled into the executable'? Since they are JavaScript and the executable is a binary how exactly are they compiled?

Comment: Any idea, how to build nodejs with any npm module inside so that you can normally call require() without first installing the module? Seems the c++ core modules can only be invoked with process.binding and not module.require.

Comment: @Aros might not be easy, but perhaps [`nexe`](https://github.com/nexe/nexe) could be an alternative?